# check a dynamic variable (is_numeric($$variable))

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a dynamic variable contains only numbers but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 34
```

And

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 38
```

What I'm really trying is to dynamically declare variables from a large form, based on a whitelist (but not for the array keys, instead I preg_replace them).

```
$list = array('name' => 'mandatory', 'surname' => 'optional');

foreach ( $list as $name => $nouse ) {
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
        if ( is_array($_POST[$name]) ) {
            $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY );
            foreach ($$name as $key => $value) {
                $key = preg_replace('[a-z]', '', $key);
                if ( is_numeric($$name[$key]) ) { // this is line 34
                    $$key = (int) $$name[$key];
                    echo $report[$key] = $key . ' variable (from ' . $name . ' ) created1... <span style="color:green;">OK!</span><br>';
                } else {
                    $$key = $$name[$key];  // this is line 38
                    echo $report[$key] = $key . ' variable (from ' . $name . ' ) created2... <span style="color:green;">OK!</span><br>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ( is_numeric($_POST[$name]) ) {
                $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
                echo $report[$name] = $name . ' variable created3... <span style="color:green;">OK!</span><br>';
            } else {
                $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
                echo $report[$name] = $name . ' variable created4... <span style="color:green;">OK!</span><br>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($list[$name] == 'optional') {
            $$name = 0;
            echo $report[$name] = $name . ' (optional) variable not filled5... <span style="color:green;">OK!</span><br>';
        } else die('Error: You must fill all mandatory fields! (' . $name . ')');
    }
}
```

The error triggers when the name points to a post array name. The html is simple:

```
<input type="text" name="address_book[name]" />
<input type="text" name="address_book[surname]" />
```

EDIT: I found a mistake, but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. The `$name` variable from the `address_book[name]` array was overwriting the `$name` variable from the first foreach, now the messages are working ok:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 34

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 38
name variable (from address_book ) created2... OK!

Warning: Illegal string offset 'surname' in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 34

Warning: Illegal string offset 'surname' in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: a in /home/aet/website.com/pages/upload.php on line 38
surname variable (from address_book ) created2... OK!
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your problem, but a piece of general advice - dynamic variables of this sort are generally much more trouble than they're worth. Just use `$filtered_data[$name]` instead of `$$name`, and your code will be much easier to read and debug.

Comment: Your validation is also extremely odd - if I fill out any text field with "1.5", it will be rejected as not an integer, but if I fill out my age as "NOYB" it will be accepted fine, because you are basing your validation on what is supplied, not what you expect.

Comment: Surprisingly `$filtered_data[$name]` is working, now there are no error messages. The fields are not meant for decimals or commas, but you are absolutly right, is odd, in part because there user can add new values if the one he needs does not exist (I work with integers in db and link them to another table with the name, so the user can create a new one, if is not integer then a new one is added). But the age example, I need to figure a fix for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are muddling variables and reusing them for multiple purposes. There are probably multiple issues here.

In one particular case I can see, you are overwriting `$key` and then using it to index back into the array:

```
foreach ($$name as $key => $value) {
    $key = preg_replace('[a-z]', '', $key);
    if ( is_numeric($$name[$key]) ) {
```

Removing the `$$` notation and giving (slightly) better variable names, this becomes:

```
foreach ($filtered_value as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
    $sanitised_sub_key = preg_replace('[a-z]', '', $sub_key);
    if ( is_numeric($filtered_value[$sanitised_sub_key]) ) {
```

When what you meant to say was:

```
    if ( is_numeric($filtered_value[$sub_key]) ) {
```

Or more simply:

```
    if ( is_numeric($sub_value) ) {
```

This is a good example of why *variable names matter*. By extension I consider dynamic variables *always* a bad idea - *you* should be choosing what to call a variable, and if you have a set of related variables, they should be in an array, so you can name the set. (e.g. `$filtered_input[$field_name]`, not `$$field_name`).

Comment: The array indexes are meant to only contain lowercase letters so I clean them. Now that they are just letters I think there's nothing to worry about? In case someone modify them I just check if `$stmt->error` and `die('Database Error');`. I could also whiteliste them, but I'm not sure how to do it simply, and not a mess.